# Integration that I coudn't figure out

Tags: integration

I am not mathematician but an engineer. At some stage of derivation for a formulation I've just been stuck with the following integration which might be super easy and stupid question for all of you as a professional mathematician but your help is so much valuable for me.

$$
\delta J = \int \frac{du}{dx} \frac{d (\delta u)}{dx} dx
$$

where $$ \delta $$ is variational operator which functions as

$$
\frac{d(\delta u)}{dx} = \delta \frac{du}{dx}
$$

and

$$
\int \delta dx = \delta \int u dx
$$

for differential and integral operators.

The term $$ \delta J$$ is supposed to yield to

$$
\int \frac{du}{dx} \frac{d (\delta u)}{dx} dx = \delta \int \frac{1}{2} (\frac{du}{dx})^2 dx 
$$

To be able to get this what I did was to take the variational operator out of the integral as the commutative rules are applied as instructed above.

$$
\int \frac{du}{dx} \delta \frac{du}{dx} dx = \delta \int \frac{du}{dx} \frac{du}{dx} dx = \delta \int (\frac{du}{dx})^2 dx
$$

where 1/2 doesn't appear.

As a result I am not able to understand where the 1/2 coefficient is coming from.

Comment: I think you're missing a rule... you need a product rule, something like $\delta (uv) = u \delta v + v \delta u$, as well.  Nothing in what you wrote allows you to move $du/dx$ "inside" the $\delta$, i.e., to go from $(du/dx) \delta (du/dx)$ to $\delta (du/dx)^2$.  But using the product rule, you can write $\delta (du/dx)^2 = 2(du/dx)\delta(du/dx)$, which is where the $1/2$ comes from.